# Zend framework rewrite mode css, javascript

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

my hataccess:

```
addDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

my index.php in THE ROOT

```
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

all the requests are redirected to the index.php, and then this INDEX.PHP requires the public/index.php - so the applicaiton works, but there is one problem is that the css, javascript files can't be loaded because they are redirected too, how to fix this?

by default they should link to mysite.com/public/css/style.css, but they are linked to mysite.com/css/style.css - that doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In this case you just get the file requested (RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]) in case of a file with size greater than 0 (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s), a symbolic link (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l) or a directory (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d). In all other cases you get the rewrite to index.php (RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L])